# How to access a variable that was created in a transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using rails 4.2

I have two db calls that both need to exist OR both not exist, so I'm using transactions inside a method in order to do that. I also want the variable I am creating to be accessible by other places in the same method. Do I just need to use an instance variable instead of a local variable? (for this I am using `puts` as an example of other code, the code am planning to execute is much more complicated than that).

```
def method_name
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    record = another_method(1)
    another_method(record)
  end
  puts record.id
end
```

If I ran this code, it throws this:

```
undefined local variable or method `record' for #<Class:...>
```

but changing `record` to `@record` will alleviate this. Is that really the best option? Or is there a better/more elegant way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Declare `record` within method scope:

```
def method_name
  record = nil # ⇐ THIS

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    record = another_method(1)
  end
  puts record.id #⇒ ID or NoMethodError if `another_method` did not succeed
end
```

---

Generally speaking, this approach is a code smell and is prohibited in most modern languages (where inner `record` would be closured and the outer remain unchanged.) The correct approach would be probably to make `transaction` to return a value and assign it to the record:

```
def method_name
  record, another_record =
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      [another_method(1), another_method(2)]
    end
  puts record.id if record
end
```

Comment: That looks good. But how would I write the second example if I only want 'record' returned as a variable and not 'another_record'?

Comment: `record = ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { another_method() }`.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. I've updated the complexity I'm facing into my question. Essentially I still want to run 'another_method' twice, but 'record' is the variable name for only the first time it is run. Then when it is run the second time, 'record' is also passed in as a variable into that. Sorry if that causes confusion.

Comment: I do not follow. Assign the local variable inside a block and return it from the block, assigning the outer variable as shown above. `record = ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { r = another_method(1); another_method(r); r }`.

Comment: Ah okay, I think that is the most suitable way to write it. Thanks!